# Git continues to push files that I already deleted

Tags: git, github

Since I have a large file in the commit, git shows error of file being too large. I deleted the original file, and I committed it, the git shows the modes are deleted. But when I tried to push them to github, the error message shows again saying the file is too big. But I've already deleted it?

`remote: error: File public/images/projects/project2/video.mp4 is 163.69 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`

But the directory does not have project2 this folder anymore. Why this happens?

Comment: As the original commit still has large file, git is still uploading it to remote. Checkout one version prior to adding large file into a new branch, add rest of the files except the large file and create a new commit. Now create a PR from this new branch. It should work.

Comment: Is the large file present in some previous commit on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, try locally to remove your [large file from the repository history](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/), following "[Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)", which typically involves using the [BFG repo cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

Then force push your repo (since its history will have changed) and see if you still have the error message.